# order list of objects by date

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
    List<object> myList = new List<object>();
    myList.orderBy(x => x.Date);
```

I need to order myList by date, but because it's a list of objects I'm having trouble re-ordering it.

I believe I can do this using IEnumerable:

```
    IEnumerable<object> receivedData = new List<object>();
```

but I'm not sure how to order it. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may use reflection

```
var orderedList = myList
                 .OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Date").GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
```

Comment: @user2320462: But the important question is, why do you store something in a `List<object>` that has a property `Date`? Use a `List<CustomType>` instead and avoid reflection.

Comment: @user2320462 I must add a +1 to Tim !

Comment: @TimSchmelter because I'm making a library that will be able to modify any type of data lists, as long as they contain specific fields.

Comment: @user2320462: Then i would use interfaces and/or generics (with constraints).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cast it into the class you want. `object` doesn't have a property called `Date`. Your class does.

You can do this in a few ways, one way is using the `as` keyword.